# Using fillna, downcast and pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I've searched for something to help me understand the keyword argument `downcast` in the class method `DataFrame.fillna`.  Please provide an example to help facilitate my and everyone's learning: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html

Also if you can say a word or two about type setting on a column by column basis with `NaN` or even `NoneType` values in the column and how to handle such common stuff.  And what the difference between those two are.

Thank you very much!

Comment: There is extensive documentation here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html; downcast is essentially an internal parameter, you don't need it. Use ``NaN``, never ``None`` (which will be converted anyhow, except in ``object`` dtyped columns).

Comment: @Jeff, sometimes I get None in a result in a SQL query in a string column which shows up as dtype object.  In that case I don't know how to convert to NaN. Thanks I'll check out the docs!

Comment: To convert to NaN use: df.fillna(value=np.NaN)

Answer (score 4):

Despite what doc says:

> **downcast** : *dict, default is None*
>
> a dict of item->dtype of what to
>   downcast if possible, or the string ‘infer’ which will try to downcast
>   to an appropriate equal type (e.g. float64 to int64 if possible)

if you supply dict as `downcast` you'll get `AssertionError("dtypes as dict is not supported yet")`

One can use only `downcast='infer'` which cause pandas to try to downcast for example floats to integers. But this seems to be buggy: If all floats in column are over 10000 it loses precision and converts them to integers.

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
   ...: import numpy as np
   ...: df = pd.DataFrame([[3.14,9999.9,10000.1,200000.2],[2.72,9999.9,10000.1,300000.3]], columns=list("ABCD"))
   ...: df.dtypes
   ...: 
Out[1]: 
A    float64
B    float64
C    float64
D    float64
dtype: object

In [2]: df
Out[2]: 
      A       B        C         D
0  3.14  9999.9  10000.1  200000.2
1  2.72  9999.9  10000.1  300000.3

In [3]: dff=df.fillna(0, downcast='infer')
   ...: dff.dtypes
   ...: 
Out[3]: 
A    float64
B    float64
C      int64
D      int64
dtype: object

In [4]: dff
Out[4]: 
      A       B      C       D
0  3.14  9999.9  10000  200000
1  2.72  9999.9  10000  300000
```

Comment: It is now fixed